# python indentation error (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, indentation

All my code is written in sublime text within Ubuntu

I'm currently learning machine learning and have been following along a video...
My code was identical to the Youtuber's code, yet I kept getting a

```
    File "deep-net.py", line 31
    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

This error message had a little caret pointing at the final closing "}" at the end of line 31. 
Here is my a segment of my code for context :

```
def neural_network_model(data):

    # (input_data + weights) + biases

    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}
    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}
    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}        #this is line 31
    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    #blah blah more code
    return output
```

Originally, I didn't put all my code on one line, since I don't like code that crawls off the screen. Here's my original indentation:

```
def neural_network_model(data):

    # (input_data + weights) + biases

    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                    'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}
```

I got the same error, except the error was at Line 35:

```
    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
```

and the caret was pointing at the ending ","

I decided put each variable definition in one line instead of breaking it into two to see if the indentation error would disappear, but it didn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a student and have spent most of my time coding Java, so I'm not used to dealing with indentation issues as of now.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using only spaces OR tabs for indentation. [Sublime text has a "convert tabs to spaces"](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/indentation.html) feature that is useful for this.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only find this in the unofficial docs, but I also use a setting `"draw_white_space": "all",` to show the whitespace characters (spaces appear as dot, tabs appear as a solid line) which is helpful for knowing when this happens: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/settings.html#whitespace-and-indentation